# Ionic 4, special character appear before form tag

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a very strange issue in my ionic 4 app... a special character appear before form

[image: Here is how my form looks like]

I used google devtools but i couldn't figure out how the character get injected before the form

[image: google devTools image]

please if someone already experienced this problem, help me to get rid of the character.

Here is my from source code

```
 ￼<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchForm.value)">
        <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom">
            <ion-label stacked>{{"SEARCH.PROPERTY_TYPE" | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-select formControlName="cat">
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.id">{{type.name}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom">
            <ion-label stacked>{{"SEARCH.DISTRICT" | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-select formControlName="district" multiple="true">
                <ion-select-option *ngFor="let estate of estates" [value]="estate.id">{{estate.title.rendered}}</ion-select-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom">
            <ion-label position="floating">{{"SEARCH.MAX_PRICE" | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="pmax" type="number"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom">
            <ion-label position="floating">{{"SEARCH.MIN_PRICE" | translate}}</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="pmin" type="number"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item class="ion-margin-bottom">
            <ion-label position>{{"SEARCH.NB_ROOM" | translate}}</ion-label>

       </ion-item>

       <ion-segment formControlName="nbroom" color="primary" class="ion-padding">
        <ion-segment-button value="1">1+</ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="2">2+</ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="3">3+</ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="4">4+</ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>

        <ion-button expand="block" icon-start color="primary" size="default" class="ion-margin-top" type="submit">
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
          {{"SEARCH_TITLE" | translate}}
        </ion-button>        
    </form>
```

Comment: But you have it in your template  check source code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your source code you have that character before form. Try to delete everything before form tag

Comment: Thanks a lot, i fixed that by changing the encoding from utf8 to iso88596, delete the special character and get back to utf8 again.